# "Смотреть НА лик нерукотворный" или "Смотреть В лик нерукотворный"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Как лучше говорить?
1. Смотреть на лик нерукотворный
2. Смотреть в лик нерукотворный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Лучше сказать: **смотреть на лик нерукотворный.**

Так обычно говорят, когда смотрят **на изображение** чего-либо.

Пример: 
― Я люблю смотреть на лицо Венеры Боттичелли. [Юрий Азаров. Подозреваемый (2002)]

2) **В лицо обычно смотрят** реальным людям, например:

Подоспевший официант, стараясь не смотреть **в лицо** Куликову, распахнул перед ним дверь... [Евгений Сухов. (2007)]

Хотя **на лицо** тоже смотрят:

Феля мог сколько угодно смотреть на лицо Софьи и не уставал от этого занятия. [Виктор Астафьев.  (1995)]

В лицо смотрят при разговоре, при каком-то контакте, а на лицо можно смотреть издали, незаметно для этого человека.

3) **Варианты** при употреблении предлогов связаны **с их значением:** действие направлено внутрь предмета (предлог В) или действие направлено на поверхность предмета (предлог НА).

Comment: Думаю, что смотрят  на лик (на изображение, вероятно),  а в лик можно вглядываться.